Linking testrail test runs in azure dev ops
We have been utilizing TestRail for our testing processes and have successfully integrated it with Azure DevOps to some extent.
However, we are facing an issue where we cannot view TestRail test run results directly in Azure DevOps. Could anyone please advise if there is an existing solution for this?
Currently, we can:

Create a bug in TestRail and push it to Azure DevOps.
Reference Azure DevOps tickets within TestRail.



However, we are facing an issue where we cannot view TestRail test run results directly in Azure DevOps. Could anyone please advise if there is an existing solution for this?

I'm afraid there is no built-in feature to view TestRail test run results directly in Azure DevOps.
TestRail test run results are tracked in different way, although it's supported to export as xml, csv or excel, but it cannot be parsed in devops directly.

Even for summary reports of test run results, it only supports html and PDF format which cannot be parsed in DevOps directly as well.
